# How to search combobox item in windows phone app 8.1?

Tags: search, combobox, windows-phone-8.1

In my Combobox somany items are there.Whenever I click the combobox it shows items list.But not there any search option.How do I search particular item.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add a search TextBox and based on the text inside, filter the ComboBox items.

Comment: @Barnstokkr   where will add  textbox .I want to whenever I click combobox it will shows items with search textbox.how it will write.please tell me.